# Selecting All the view in Telerik RadGrid

Tags: javascript, asp.net, checkbox, telerik, dom-events

In Telerik Grid,suppose we add a `gridclientselect` column, and `checkall` is checked only rows in current view is selected, but my purpose is to mimic the user that rows in all the views are selected. So I added a checkbox column as gridbound column. My purpose is when the user checks on the header checkbox, I should show as all the rows in all views are selected. This is achieved through Javascript and asp.net code. Could you please provide  some links for this type of functionality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My proposal is to use a template column with asp checkboxes inside it as in [this sample](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/grid/examples/programming/selectrowwithcheckbox/defaultcs.aspx) and when the header checkbox is checked, mark all grid items as selected via their Selected property and repeat that operation on rebind operations like sorting, paging, filtering, etc.

Comment: Thank you very much dick.it works fine for me at the expense of a negligible performance.